# WCF BaseAddress Issue and EndPoint Issue Not Working

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-binding

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"></compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" faultExceptionEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="WcfRestService.Infrastructure.BasicAuthenticationManager, WcfRestService" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule"
           type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />

    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd"
           type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the
>   endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes.
>   I am running it from visual studio how to run it on local.
>   are [http].

Comment: Is there any reason why there is no <endpoints> tag within your <system.servicemodel> tag?

Comment: @Zack - endpoints are not required in WCF 4.0+.  If an endpoint isn't explicitly defined, a default endpoint with `basicHttpBinding` will be used.

Comment: What about a <services> tag? Such as system.serviceModel/services/service/host/baseAddresses/add@baseAddress="https://localhost:8080/ServiceName"

Comment: @Zack:  Nope.  Take a look at [A Developer's Introduction to Windows Communication Foundation 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx).  You can have a hosted WCF service with no `<system.serviceModel>` tag in the config (though you'll get `basicHttpBinding` and all the related defaults).

Comment: how to add end point in this web.config i dont know how i am new.

Comment: i have uploaded my project on http://speedy.sh/7Q68t/WcfRestService.rar Please Make the Changes to run the project and upload it.thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can try explicitly mapping `webHttpBinding` to the `https` protocol in your config file, like this:

```
<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="https" binding="webHttpBinding" />
</protocolMapping>
```

This goes in your `<system.serviceModel>` section.  This will tell the service to use `webHttpBinding` by default for `https` requests (IIRC, `basicHttpsBinding` is the WCF default for `https`).

Comment: i have uploaded my project on http://speedy.sh/7Q68t/WcfRestService.rar Please Make the Changes to run the project and upload it.thank you